# How to parse nested JSON objects with JSON framework and Objective-C/iPhone/Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, json

I'm writing an iPhone native app using the JSON framework.

My app is accessing web services using JSON. The JSON data we send has nested objects, below is an example of the data served up:

```
{
    "model": {
        "JSONRESPONSE": {
            "authenticationFlag": true,
            "sessionId": "3C4AA754D77BFBE33E0D66EBE306B8CA",
            "statusMessage": "Successful Login.",
            "locId": 1,
            "userName": "Joe Schmoe"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having problem parsing using the objectForKey and valueForKey NSDictionary methods. I keep getting invalidArgumentException runtime errors.

For instance, I want to query the response data for the "authenticationFlag" element.

Thanks,
Mike
Seattle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is hard to tell without some more details (e.g. the JSON parsing code that you are using), but two things strike me as possible:

1. you are not querying with a full path. In the case above, you'd need to first get the enclosing model, the json response, and only then ask the json response dictionary for the authenticationFlag value:

   `[[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"model"]
   objectForKey:@"JSONRESPONSE"] objectForKey:@"authenticationFlag"]`
2. perhaps you're using c-strings (`""`) rather than NSStrings (`@""`) as keys (although this would likely crash nastily or just not compile). The key should be something than can be cast to id.

While possible, both are probably false, so please include more detail.

Comment: Solution 1 worked. Essentially, I needed to traverse down to the JSONRESPONSE node then I could access the desired element. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following is taken directly from Dan Grigsby's Tutorial at - http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/ - Please attribute, stealing is bad karma.

Fetching JSON Over HTTP

We’ll use Cocoa’s NSURLConnection to issue an HTTP request and retrieve the JSON data.

Cocoa provides both synchronous and asynchronous options for making HTTP requests. Synchronous requests run from the application’s main runloop cause the app to halt while it waits for a response. Asynchronous requests use callbacks to avoid blocking and are straightforward to use. We’ll use asynchronous requests.

First thing we need to do is update our view controller’s interface to include an NSMutableData to hold the response data. We declare this in the interface (and not inside a method) because the response comes back serially in pieces that we stitch together rather than in a complete unit.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}
```

To keep things simple, we’ll kick off the HTTP request from viewDidLoad.

Replace the contents of :

```
#import "JSON/JSON.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"XYZ.json"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This mostly boilerplate code initializes the responseData variable to be ready to hold the data and kicks off the connection in viewDidload; it gathers the pieces as they come in in didReceiveData; and the empty connectionDidFinishLoading stands ready to do something with the results.
Using The JSON Data

Next, we’ll flesh out the connectionDidFinishLoading method to make use of the JSON data retrieved in the last step.

Update the connectionDidFinishLoading method :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSArray *luckyNumbers = [responseString JSONValue];

    NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Lucky numbers:\n"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [luckyNumbers count]; i++)
        [text appendFormat:@"%@\n", [luckyNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];

    label.text =  text;
}
```

It creates an NSArray. The parser is very flexible and returns objects — including nested objects — that appropriately match JSON datatypes to Objective-C datatypes.
Better Error Handling

Thus far, we’ve been using the the convenient, high-level extensions to NSString method of parsing JSON. We’ve done so with good reason: it’s handy to simple send the JSONValue message to a string to accessed to the parsed JSON values.

Unfortunately, using this method makes helpful error handling difficult. If the JSON parser fails for any reason it simply returns a nil value. However, if you watch your console log when this happens, you’ll see messages describing precisely what caused the parser to fail.

It’d be nice to be able to pass those error details along to the user. To do so, we’ll switch to the second, object-oriented method, that the JSON SDK supports.

Update the connectionDidFinishLoading method in :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSError *error;
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSArray *luckyNumbers = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
    [responseString release];   

    if (luckyNumbers == nil)
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"JSON parsing failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
    else {
        NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Lucky numbers:\n"];

        for (int i = 0; i < [luckyNumbers count]; i++)
            [text appendFormat:@"%@\n", [viewcontroller objectAtIndex:i]];

        label.text =  text;
    }
}
```

Using this method gives us a pointer to the error object of the underlying JSON parser that we can use for more useful error handling.

Conclusion :

The JSON SDK and Cocoa's built-in support for HTTP make adding JSON web services to iPhone apps straightforward.

Comment: I have a json format like this, how can I use  please help me.         jsont({
  "id": "ntp-a1.nict.go.jp",
  "it": 1232963971.248,
  "st": 1344228610.961,
  "leap": 34,
  "next": 1341100800,
  "step": 1
})

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString* aStr;
    aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [aStr JSONValue];
    NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];

    // values in foreach loop
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSArray *items = (NSArray *) [dictionary objectForKey:key];  

        for (id *item in items) {  


            NSString* aStrs=  item;
            NSLog(@" test %@", aStrs);

            NSDictionary *dict = aStrs;
            NSArray *k = [dict allKeys];

        for (id *it in k) {  
                            NSLog(@"the  child item: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Child Item -> %@ value %@", (NSDictionary *) it,[dict objectForKey:it]]);                
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, Objective c has introduced in build class for JSON Parsing.

```
 NSError *myError = nil;
 NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

So utilize this class and make your application error free...:)