# how to parse json multi dimenstional array in titanium or xcode

Tags: xcode, drupal, titanium

My drupal developer given a url like:http://feed.local/feed/services/rest/viewget/test.json
then am getting the out put as(when am browsing from chrome browser) below:

```
[{"nid":"133","node_title":"What is life really all about?"},{"nid":"139","node_title":"What went wrong?"}]
```

I am using sumitk tutorial that is how to develop iphone app using drupal as base system with titanium.
My problem is how can i parse the above in titanium .Can any one help.....
Or else If any one help me how can i use this in xcode........

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Titanium.JSON.parse](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.JSON.parse-method)

Comment: See these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165290/how-to-parsing-json-object-in-iphone-sdk-xcode-using-json-framework or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692247/how-to-parse-nested-json-objects-with-json-framework-and-objective-c-iphone-xcod

Comment: [{"nid":"133","node_title":"What is life really all about?"},{"nid":"139","node_title":"What went wrong?"}]                          how can i place "node_title" in table view...? Can u help......that above json is coming from url.....

Comment: When you will extract out the json data, you can put it in table view as a label or row title.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse will help you, it is a function included by Titanium. Make sure you encapsulate it within a try {} catch(excp) {}

For example:

```
try
{
   var data = JSON.parse('[{"nid":"133","node_title":"What is life really all about?"},{"nid":"139","node_title":"What went wrong?"}]');
}
catch (excp)
{
   alert('JSON parse error');
}
```